# Ubuntu installer toggle between command line and installer

Tags: command-line

I'm running the ubuntu server installer, I configure my network settings, and I want to go to command line to verify that the NIC is connected before continuing the install. So I go to the help menu and select command line. I'm able to test the NIC settings, but how to I toggle back to the installer? I've seen it done before, but I just can't recall the key combination to get me back to the installation screen

Comment: Try `exit` command.

Comment: perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

```
exit
```

command to get out of the shell session.